# How to estimate power attenuation of a laser using distance and divergence?

Tags: laser

Whats the attenuation relation for a laser power or intensity for a given beam angle and distance?

For instance, if the beam angle is 2 degree and the distance is 10cm whats the power attenuation?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no absorption as it travels, the power in the beam does not change. The total power is the same at any distance. The beam expands and the cross sectional area grows. The power per unit area, or intensity, decreases.

If you are far from the laser, the beam is an expanding cone. The cross sectional area is proportional to the distance. So intensity goes as $1/d$.

It is more complicated close to the laser. Light is a wave. Rays are an approximation to the direction the wave travels. Rays are not always straight. Close to a laser, they are hyperbolic. See [Gaussian Beams](https://www.rp-photonics.com/gaussian_beams.html) for more.

Most lasers would have a divergence angle must less than $2$ degrees. A few milliradians would be typical. $1$ milliradian $= 0.57^o$.